# Geocoder Gem .near working for distances over 1000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the Geocoder Gem. When I use `.near` I get no results unless I set the distance to 500 to 1000.

I created this query:

```
User.near([53.2910642, -6.1969235], 20).any?
```

But do not get any results, but:

```
User.near([53.2910642, -6.1969235], 2000).any?
```

Does. I have a user in the database.

I have a user in the database with a latitude of 53.2910642 and longitude of -6.1969235. These are stored in Float columns and in the User model I have:

```
#Geocoding
geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode
```

Is their something obvious that I am missing? I am testing this in the test environment, in the Rails Console.

Comment: It sounds OK to me, if the 20 miles radius doesn't give you results while the 2000 gives you results, it could simply mean that all the results are within a 20+ range.

Comment: You might want to make sure that you're storing your coordinates using a `decimal` type with the following options: precision: 15 and scale: 10.

Comment: @Doodloo, Thanks for coming back so fast. The doc says to use Float and set the search to the exact same location in the database. I will try it with decimal.

Comment: Fixed it, I had to change the data type to :DECIMAL, precision: 8, scale: 6 and that seems to have worked on the local server, to be tested on Heroku.

Comment: See if my proposed answer make sense for you. Also, you might want to check my note about indexing your coordinate columns... The queries that are issued to the database backend make heavy use of math-based operators, having them indexed (Or even pre-baked with redundant mathematic results in some special occasions) is important.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database backend you're using, floating-point precision might be different than what you expect.

Eg you might want to check that you're at least using a precision of 15 and a scale of 10. A rails column migration would be created using:

```
[ :longitude, :latitude ].each do |c|
  t.decimal c, precision: 15, scale: 10
  t.decimal c, precision: 15, scale: 10
end
```

Also, if you're planning to query your database for entries based on their location, make sure you're using correct index for those columns!

The queries that are issued to a database backend for querying a distance between two coordinates could be heavy. When I worked on similar projects, I ended up rewriting this kind of functionality to allow my models to store intermediate values.

For instance, if your distance computation formula looks like the one described here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, you might want to create indexed columns to store the result of φ1 and φ2, as well as columns to store results of the cosine / sine of φ1 and φ2.

This way, you will be able to optimize the database queries and greatly improve run times.

Another approach I ended up using was to do a rough bounding-box based SQL query based on the radius, returning a list of candidates for a more complex geodesic based formula. This way, the geodesic SQL formula could either pre-select candidates using the IN [...] operator, or even completely be by-passed and be done with your code using the candidates array.